# in python codding, how can I append output of each iteration to separate variable

Tags: python, excel, tkinter, openpyxl, global

I am trying to merging the excel file program. The first step that I need to do is to check the excel file selected. This is the part of coding that I have done.

```
import os
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter.messagebox as msgbox
from tkinter import *  # __all__
from tkinter import filedialog
from datetime import datetime
from openpyxl import Workbook

def add_file():
    files = filedialog.askopenfilenames(title="파일을 선택하세요", \
                                    filetypes=(('xls 파일', '*.xls'), ('xlsx 파일', '*.xlsx'), ('모든 파일', '*.*')), \
                                    initialdir='D:/사업/발주 및 정산/정산/정산서') 
    for file in files:
        list_file.insert(END, file)

def del_file():
    for index in reversed(list_file.curselection()):  
        list_file.delete(index)

def btncmd():
    wb = Workbook()  
    ws = wb.active  

    print(file)

datestring = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y%m%d') 

    wb.save("D:/사업/발주 및 정산/정산/정산서/리빙투게더 정산서 " + datestring + ".xls") 
    wb.close()

btn = Button(frame_folder, text='클릭', command=btncmd)
btn.pack(side='left', padx=6, pady=5)
```

I want to take output of "file" variable, and use it in def btncmd(): but it doesn't work. How can I take the output of file in def add_file(): and append the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initiated variable "file"- you only use it within the loop where it works as just different name of index number, so every iteration is just called "file". Print "file" at the end of loop (within it) or append output of each iteration to separate variable and than print that variable.

Edit: iteration example

file_content = []

for file in files:
list_file.insert(END, file)
file_content.append(file)

OR

for file in files:
a = list_file.insert(END, file)
file_content.append(a)

Depending on which output you want to use later on in the code.

Comment: def btncmd(): has function and it is related to def add_file(): and other modules, so the location cannot move. In order to use "file" in "def btncmd():", how can I do?

Comment: Will content of that variable be just strings? If yes, before function add_file initiate empty list variable for example  "file_content=[]" and at the end of "for file in files" loop add "file_content.append(file)" with the same indentation as the previous line. This way you can use "file" content outside loop as well. If you need only certain element from that list to be used afterwards just use list indexing for example "file_content[number_of_needed_item]"